# VoiceOver: have UITableViewCell pose as UISlider

Tags: uitableview, uislider, voiceover

I have made a custom UITableViewCell which contains a UISlider and three UILabel : the title (name of the slider), the current value, the minimum value and the maximum value.

When using VoiceOver, isAccessibilityElement=NO on that cell, therefore the user has to select the UISlider as a subitem of the UITableViewCell before doing the double-drag gesture (touch, untouch, touch, move left/right, untouch) for modifying the value. I would like to have the whole UITableViewCell pretend it is the UISlider. So I set isAccessibilityElement=YES and then I can't figure out what I need to override in my subclass of UITableViewCell so that it route any relevant messages to UISlider.

When I double-drag the slider, I hear the sounds that mean that I successfully began a gesture for modifying the value, but it stops there.

I tried UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable but then -accessibilityDecrement and -accessibilityIncrement do not cover all that can be done with a slider. I can't seem to find what method(s) is/are called when the user does a double-drag left/right. I tried overriding -touchesMoved: (among other things) but I don't receive any calls.

I even tried using a fake object for logging all method calls, using -forwardInvocation: and -methodSignatureForSelector: for sending to the real object, until I found that UIKit does not allow fake objects (weird message about -superlayer not found), therefore I can't log what gets sent by VoiceOver to a UISlider (or to a UITableViewCell with isAccessibilityElement=YES).

So, what am I missing ?

Comment: Just checking: you set `isAccessibilityElement = YES` on the cell, then set `UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable ` on the cell which had the effect of VoiceOver starting to announce "Adjustable" on the cell, then overrode `accessibilityIncrement`/`accessibilityDecrement` on the cell, then with VoiceOver on, landed the cursor on the cell, made sure "Adjust value" is selected in the Rotor (using the two-finger "screw" gesture), then tried adjusting the value (by flicking up/down with one finger), and your overrides for `accessibilityIncrement`/`accessibilityDecrement` did not get called?

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake in explaining the problem. I didn't know how increment/decrement were supposed to be activated. You showed me how to, and now my slider supports the up/down flicks. The initial problem that I wanted to state (and the only one that remains) is about how to reproduce the double-drag (a double-click in which the 2nd click is a left/right drag allowing to set the slider to any value without having to flick).

Comment: Hi, I just found a workaround. The cell stops exposing itself as a VoiceOver item, using this :

- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount {return 1;}
- (id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {return d;}
- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element {return 0;}

where d is the UISlider*.

Comment: Is there still something to figure out or have you found out a solution for your topic ? In this case, could you write an UPDATE and close the topic, please ?

Comment: Hi, I did get it to work sometime in 2015 I think, but I don't  remember what was missing exactly, nor whether I had to improve my solution before the "workaround" mentioned above. I didn't think anyone really wanted to know the answer. I don't know what's "closing a topic" on this website, and I probably haven't logged in since 2015, as SO's reputation system prevents from helping others and as I didn't have any questions that would be more popular or easier to answer...